# Generic cryptarithmetic puzzle asked in my exam

Tags: artificial-intelligence, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

```
 ONE +
 ONE +
 TWO =
______
FOUR
```

Can anybody can solve this cryptarithmetic in step by step process
Thank you

Comment: Your question is interesting, but you should at least try some of your own.

Answer (score 0):

Prolog can do it! (after all this is Stackoverflow and you have tagged your question [artificial-intelligence](/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence))

```
solution(O, N, E, T, W, F, U, R) :-
    /* All different */
    select(O, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], L1),
    select(N, L1, L2),
    select(E, L2, L3),
    select(T, L3, L4),
    select(W, L4, L5),
    select(F, L5, L6),
    select(U, L6, L7),
    member(R, L7),

    /* Constraints */
    FOUR is F * 1000 + O * 100 + U * 10 + R,
    ONE is O * 100 + N * 10 + E,
    TWO is T * 100 + W * 10 + O,

    FOUR is ONE + ONE + TWO.
```

The general idea is to select all the variables at first and then check the puzzle conditions.

Now

```
?- solution(O,N,E,T,W,F,U,R).
```

will print the first solution found. With:

```
?- aggregate_all(count, (solution(O,N,E,T,W,F,U,R)), Count).
```

You can see that there are `173` distinct solutions.

Tracing the execution of the query allows you to see all of the goals that are executed as part of the query, in sequence, along with whether or not they succeed (it also allows you to see what steps occur as Prolog backtracks):

```
?- trace, solution(O,N,E,T,W,F,U,R).
```

(you can use the [online SWI-Prolog](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/) platform to play with the example).

---

Traditionally (in [verbal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_arithmetic)):

> each letter should represent a different digit, and (as in ordinary arithmetic notation) the leading digit of a multi-digit number must not be zero. A good puzzle should have a unique solution, and the letters should make up a phrase.

You can force the "leading digit must not be zero"-rule adding:

```
not(O = 0), not(T = 0), not(F = 0).
```

anyway the problem has multiple solutions.